# Trying to display products in horizontal line

Tags: css

Not sure what I am doing wrong but I am finding it impossible to display the related products beneath the main product image in a horizontal line.

http://89.145.118.113/red-nigella-dress.html

Could someone please help me out.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should mention image/code here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
.block-content li.item {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

This should point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the example at http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block very helpful and was able to fix the problem I was having.